# Karate 0.9.6 1.1.0 - org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: not found error when using classpath to specify the file location

Tags: java, classpath, karate

I am getting the error **"org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: not found: src\test\java\data\commonData.csv"** when using classpath to specify the file location.
I am using karate-apache version 0.9.6 & karate-core 1.1.0 dependencies in my pom.xml file and jdk version 1.8.0_321.

Below is the error trace:
* def datasource = read('classpath:src\test\java\data\commonData.csv')
js failed:
>>>>
01: read('classpath:src\test\java\data\commonData.csv')
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: not found: src\test\java\data\commonData.csv

- com.intuit.karate.resource.ResourceUtils.getResource(ResourceUtils.java:120)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioFileReader.toResource(ScenarioFileReader.java:122)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioFileReader.readFileAsStream(ScenarioFileReader.java:99)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioFileReader.readFileAsString(ScenarioFileReader.java:95)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioFileReader.readFile(ScenarioFileReader.java:68)
- com.intuit.karate.core.ScenarioEngine.lambda$new$0(ScenarioEngine.java:124)
- .:program(Unnamed:1)

Have tried specifying the path in below ways and still ended up getting the same error:

1. with one back slash

   - def datasource = read('classpath:src/test/java/data/commonData.csv')
2. with two forward slashes

- def datasource = read('classpath:src\test\java\data\commonData.csv')

Comment: these are old versions. upgrade to 1.2.0 and if you still see issues, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue